# Vaadin Grid Column Re-Order (Vaadin 14 / Flow)

Tags: grid, vaadin, vaadin14

I'm using Vaadin grid and have two grids which are more or less configured the same. One has a header row configured. I retrieve it by prependHeaderRow() method.

On both of the grids I enable column reordering by setting setColumnReorderingAllowed(true).
On both I'm then able to drag columns. BUT the one without header row lets me reorder the columns (see fig 1) and the other one prevents me from reordering by indicating all columns in grey-ish while dragging the column (fig 2).

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWc9d.png)
[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkHd1.png)

Has somebody any idea why Vaadin grid is preventing my from re-ordering while header row is prepended? And if yes how I can get around it?

Kind regards
Ben

Comment: Doesn't sound like a known issue. In which of the grids is reordering allowed? Could you share some minimal code that replicates the issue?

Comment: Hi Tarek,
thanks you for your comment. Based on your comment I was investigating a bit more and found (what I was overseeing before because I was biased of thinking about the data provider) that another difference is the prepended header row. If I exclude it from the code, both grids columns are reorderable.

I just updated the original post.

Comment: Are you calling `setColumnReorderingAllowed(true)` before or after calling `prependHeaderRow()`? The order of invocation could matter here.

Comment: Hi Ollie,
I just tried it with making the `setColumnReorderingAllowed(true)` the first call and in another test the very last call. No change in behavior.

Thanks
Ben